# Why do a span and an img element have different vertical positions in the same line?

Tags: html, css

Although the heights of span and img elements are the same, they are located in different vertical positions i.e their "y" coordinates are different. What is the basic idea behind this?

The HTML code:

```
<p>
    <span> Foo </span>
    <span> Bar </span>
    <img src="http://www.oriental-weaponry.co.uk/acatalog/68-06-RE-rattan-escrima-stick-1000.jpg" height="36" width="36"/>
</p>
```

associated CSS:

```
span { 
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
    font-size:30px;
    color:white; 
}
```

and the jsfiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lcawysvs/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `vertical-align` for an image causes it to sit on the baseline of the text. The bottom of the image is aligned with the bottom of the letters (discounting the descenders that you might find on letters like `y` and `g`).

[image: figure 1]

You can change that with, for example:

```
img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the `vertical-align` on the `img` or `span` because `inline` elements sit on the `baseline` by default:

```
span { 
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
  font-size:30px;
  color:white; 
  text-align:center;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcawysvs/6/)